# Stuck on where to insert a line break when there are no quotation marks

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, line-breaks

I'v done a code challenge and one of the extras was write a line of code that prints the previous result (which I have done)

```
print(str(year)*int(number))
```

but it also says to put a line break between each returned value.
So for example the var 'year' returns an int and that int gets printed a certain
amount of times depending on what the users input is.

I just can't figure out where the '\n' will go in this line of code.

```
 print(str(year)*int(number))
```

Comment: Where did you try to put it? What did not work? A -returned- value, is something different then a printed value.

Comment: just print the year in a loop? its unclear exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Are you restricted to editing the line you've given, or are you allowed to write it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple loop:

```
for _ in range(number):
    print(year)
```

This will insert the `\n` by default - as each print is a seperate command and the default `end=\n` parameter to print applies.

Patrick Haugh beat me by 50sec to use the print-commands parameter `sep` that lets you specify what to put between printed values:

```
print(1,2,3,4,sep="\n")
```

This prints a newline between each of the numbers - by default it prints a single space.

You could put the collected numbers in a list, decomposit the list in its element and print them with a \n seperator:

```
year = 18
number= 3
print( *[year]*number ,sep="\n")
```

More can be found in the

- [`print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can print a separator character between separate arguments to `print` that will appear between them instead of a space

```
print('a', 'b', sep='\n')
```

We can use argument unpacking to provide `number` many arguments to `print`, and separate them with `'\n'`

```
year = 2000
number = 5
print(*[year]*number, sep='\n')
```

prints

```
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
```